# Random Missing Fields in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm just finishing my thesis and have noticed that for some articles published in edited volumes (but not all) the city and publisher fields are missing from the bibliography. Here's a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Chiara2002,
    address = {Dordrecht},
    author = {{Dalla Chiara}, Maria Luisa and Giuntini, Roberto},
    booktitle = {Handbook of Philosophical Logic},
    edition = {2},
    editor = {Gabbay, Dov M. and Guenthner, Franz},
    pages = {129--228},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {{Quantum Logics}},
    volume = {6},
    year = {2002}
}

@incollection{Westerstahl1989,
    address = {Dordrecht},
    author = {Westerst{\aa}hl, Dag},
    booktitle = {Handbook of Philosophical Logic},
    editor = {Gabbay, Dov M. and Guenthner, Franz},
    pages = {1--131},
    publisher = {Kluwer},
    title = {{Quantifiers in Formal and Natural Languages}},
    volume = {4},
    year = {1989}
}

@incollection{Etchemendy2010,
    address = {Oxford},
    author = {Etchemendy, John},
    booktitle = {New Essays on Tarski and Philosophy},
    editor = {Patterson, Douglas},
    pages = {263--299},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    title = {{Reflections on Consequence}},
    year = {2010}
}

@incollection{Russell2018b,
    address = {Cham},
    author = {Russell, Gillian},
    booktitle = {Pluralisms in Truth and Logic},
    editor = {Wyatt, Jeremy and Pedersen, Nikolaj J. L. L. and Kellen, Nathan},
    pages = {331--361},
    publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
    title = {{Varieties of Logical Consequence by Their Resistance to Logical Nihilism}},
    year = {2018}
}

@incollection{Cotnoir2018,
    address = {Cham},
    author = {Cotnoir, Aaron J.},
    booktitle = {Pluralisms in Truth and Logic},
    editor = {Wyatt, Jeremy and Pedersen, Nikolaj J. L. L. and Kellen, Nathan},
    pages = {301--329},
    publisher = {Palgrave Macmillan},
    title = {{Logical Nihilism}},
    year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}


%%%%%%%%%%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[style=apa6, doi=false, url=false, isbn=false, date=year, natbib=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{chapter}} %gets rid of chapters
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} %stops capitalisation
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} %clears issue numbers
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}} %de-italicises volume numbers

\addbibresource{/Users/James/Documents/MWEs/\jobname.bib}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%commands to stop hyphenation in bibliography
\renewcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
    \interlinepenalty=5000\relax
    \widowpenalty=10000\relax
    \clubpenalty=10000\relax
    % no hyphenation in the bibliography
    \hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000\relax
    % increase allowed stretch to avoid overfull boxes
    \setlength{\emergencystretch}{1em}%
    \raggedbottom
    \frenchspacing
    \biburlsetup}
%%%

\title{Missing Fields MWE}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent For most references to articles in edited volumes (e.g. \citealp{Chiara2002}; \citealp{Westerstahl1989}) the bibliography is fine. However, for some articles in edited volumes, the city and publisher fields are omitted from the bibliography entry (e.g. \citealp{Cotnoir2018}; \citealp{Etchemendy2010}; \citealp{Russell2018b}). I don't understand why because the city and publisher are included in the .bib file

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image]

As you can see, both the city and publisher fields are missing for three of the entries but not the other two. How can I rectify this?

Comment: I have the city everywhere. Is you system up-to-date?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but instead of `(e.g. \citealp{Chiara2002}; \citealp{Westerstahl1989})` it is much nicer to write `\parencites(e.g.)(){Chiara2002}{Westerstahl1989}` (this also avoids the excessive space after 'e.g.' that you could fix with `(e.g.~\citealp{Chiara2002}; \citealp{Westerstahl1989})` or `(e.g.\ \citealp{Chiara2002}; \citealp{Westerstahl1989})`)

Comment: I'm with Ulrike. With a current version of `biblatex-apa6` (2020/08/28 v8.5) I do get to see publisher and locations in all entries. Same with Overleaf's TeX Live 2019 (running `biblatex-apa6` 2019/12/02 v8.3, see https://www.overleaf.com/read/rzvyvdcqmrcj).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's something to do with my the version of biblatex on my computer rather than anything in the code!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the shown effect cannot be reproduced with up-to-date versions of the involved packages. An update should help produce the expected output.